# How to write log records to existing error log file

Tags: django

The error log that my django error's get written to is highly accessible. As a result, within my code, I'd like to use this same file for my logging. My configuration looks like this.

Settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/opt/python/log/djangoerrors.log'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Within my view, I've got this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def myview(request):
    ... some code ...
    logger.error('hello. This should be logged to the error file.')
```

Unfortunately, this text isn't being written to my djangoerrors.log file. Can you see what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an entry for your app in settings.LOGGING['logger']?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Try that.  Or change the setting where you have 'django' to an empty string